# Change column in rails from integer to float

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have contact_number in my customers table using the field integer. 
I tried creating a record in rails c but apparently it can't store a larger field of numbers.
I looked around online I think I should use float instead of integer given a precision of 10 numbers like in the states

my thought is to create a new migration with

```
class ChangeContactNumberInCustomerTableToFloatFromInteger < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change_table 
    remove_column :customers, :contact_number, :integer
    add_column :customers, :contact_number, :float
  end
end
```

how do I specify the precision and is this the correct way in doing this?

Comment: Do not store telephone numbers as `float`. This type has limited precision. @Teeg's suggestion of storing as `string` make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, if I am correct that `contact_number` is a phone number, you will want to use a **string** rather than a numeric field. Phone numbers are not so much numeric values as they are a collection of digits. Or stated more generally, they are a collection of characters, which just happen to be limited to only numbers.

Additionally, it will be easier to parse the area code and country code too, if that is relevant (however hypothetically if you do need to parse country and area code, you'd want to store those in separate columns anyways, but that's a different discussion)

To answer your question directly, use the `change_column` method instead, like so:

```
change_column :customers, :contact_number, :string
```

Details found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: this answers my question well, I wasn't sure which type to use for my field

Comment: @Jngai1297 Glad to hear it. Please click the check mark on whichever answer helped you the most to accept.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> limit Sets the maximum size of the string/text/binary/integer fields
> precision Defines the precision for the decimal fields
> scale Defines the scale for the decimal fields
> polymorphic Adds a type column for belongs_to associations
> ```

here is an example:

```
class AddDetailsToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :price, precision: 5, scale: 2
    add_reference :products, :user, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end
```

from the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

and here are the types of filed you columns can accept:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column